# Can't login Google Auth with Firebase's authUI

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui, google-signin

## What I'm doing

I'm currently developing an app in Android Studio that uses Firebase for login process. In this case, we are only using Google's social login.

## Issue

I completed the implementation a few days ago and installed it on the actual device and was **able to confirm that I could log in with no problems**.
After that, when I published and tested the app on the Google play store, the app downloaded from the play store **refused to log in**.
The message I received is as follows

*Sign-in attempt failed.*

I'd like to resolve this issue.

## Code

The sign-in intent is defined by the following code.

```java
public void createSignInIntent() {
        // [START auth_fui_create_intent]
        // Choose authentication providers
        List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> providers = Arrays.asList(
                new AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build()
        );

        // Create and launch sign-in intent
        startActivityForResult(
                AuthUI.getInstance()
                        .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                        .setAvailableProviders(providers)
                        .build(),
                RC_SIGN_IN);
        // [END auth_fui_create_intent]
    }
```

This function is called at onCreate method.
And the receipt of the intent result is defined below.

```java
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            IdpResponse response = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(data);

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // Successfully signed in
                FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                CheckUsers(user);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Sign-in attempt failed.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    //...
}
```

As you can see from the above code, the resultCode is not RESULT_OK so that the login does not seem to be completed.

Please give me some pieces of advise!

Comment: you should check that you are using the right SHA-1 fingerprint of certificates in your google-services.json file, see also: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth

Comment: Show us the entire error message that you get.

Comment: The error message I always get is "com.firebase.ui.auth.FirebaseUIException:Code:10,message:10:"

Answer (score -1):

Add the App signing key (sha) certificate present in the Play Store console , present in app signing to your firebase console. And it will work fine.